# Bootstrap theme embedded iframes are distorted

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, embed, iframe

I'm trying to embed videos onto a page, but they are displaying all stretched out. [Here's what it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfqgs.jpg), and [this is what it currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Z02E.jpg).

Here's my embed code:

```
<iframe width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Fj5O0V9WWug?rel=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

... but it looks like the default css may be messing with the proportions

```
.embed-responsive-16by9 { padding-bottom: 56.25%; }
.embed-responsive .embed-responsive-item, .embed-responsive iframe, .embed-responsive embed, .embed-responsive object, .embed-responsive video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0;
}
```

Removing the above css makes the video disappear. Any suggestions on why the videos may be appearing to stretched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding some free plugin like [this one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/install-fitvids-embed-fluid-width-videos/). This plugin uses FitVids.js to make your videos fluid width. There are many more similar plugins available for free which would allow you to do this without adding any CSS.